# Using gems vs copying folders for Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a Rails App with Bootstrap 3. What is the difference between adding bootstrapp-sass to my Gemfile and simply downloading Bootstrap and copying the css and javascript files into their respective folders of the Rails app?

Comment: More of a side note, I don't believe the bootstrap 3 branch of bootstrap-sass is stable yet.

Comment: You're right! My mistake, I learned it the hard way and am using anjlab gem now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With gems you can always have the latest version if you keep your bundle up to date. If you copy the files, you will have to update manually when there are newer versions of the framework.

Comment: There is still a manual update process in both cases, it's just that it's typically easter to `bundle update bootstrap-sass` than it is to download the Bootstrap zip and manually update specific files.

Comment: Yes, that's why I specified "if you keep your bundle up to date". But thank you for the note, it will serve if he didn't know how to go about the update.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with a gem because it simplifies the updating process. No manual copy pasting makes me a happier developer.

Also, `bootstrap-sass` is a port to SASS from the official Bootstrap, which uses LESS.